# Оптимизация SELECT DISTINCT в plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql

Как я могу оптимизировать данный запрос:

```
select DISTINCT 
        p.SBJ_ID, 
    nvl(l.ATTR,c.CODE) as ATTR, 
        l.VALUE
from T_TRFPRMLST p,
       T_CMSATTR_LINK l, 
       C_SBJCONCEPT c
where l.SBJ_ID(+) = p.SBJ_ID
  and p.sbj_id = c.ID;
```

Comment: План покажите. Что с запросом не так? очень не замысловатый запрос.

Comment: Ну для начала заменить NVL на COALESCE, чтобы убрать переключение движков :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данный запрос не оптимизировать, т.к. он и так в нужном состоянии.. разве что можно его переписать по другому с JOIN, но результат будет такой же. Смысла нет.

Comment: да, порядок таблиц был неправильным